# Bounded and almost everywhere convergent in $L^1$ imply convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Here is my question.

Let $(f_n)_n \subset L^1 (\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ a bounded set, be a suquence such that

1. $(f_n)_n$ is bounded
2. $(f_n)_n$ is a.e. convergent. That is, there exists $f \in L^1 (\Omega)$ such that $f_n (x) \to f(x)$ for a.e. $x \in \Omega$.

Does this imply that $f_n \to f$ strongly in $L^1$?

If we were talking about $L^p$ for $p > 1$ this is easy, since we can use that weak convergence and a.e. convergence imply strong convergence by a applying a Césaro mean argument. Since $L^1$ is not reflexive, this argument does not apply.

Many thanks. Cheers

D

Comment: $f_n(x) = \frac{1_{|x| < 1/n}}{2/n}$, $f(x) = 0$, $\|f_n\|_{L^1} = 1$.  This is what [Terrence Tao calls](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/) "escape to vertical infinity"

Comment: When you say $f_n$ is bounded, do you mean it is uniformly bounded? i.e. $|f_n(x)| \leq M$ for some $M>0$.

Comment: anything unclear ? the difference between $p= 1$ and $p> 1$ is that $\| n \ h(nx) \|_{L^p} = n^{1-1/p}\|h(x)\|_{L^p}  $ so that for $p > 1$  : $\lim_{n \to \infty}\| n \ h(nx) \|_{L^p} = 0$ and escape to vertical infinity is impossible.

Comment: Intuitively, if $\|f_n\|_{L^p}$ is bounded,  and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ almost everywhere, say for $x \in A$, it means $\|f-f_n\|_{L^p}$ has to concentrate on the neighborhood of those $x \not \in A$ : it has to espace to vertical infinity at those points, which is possible only when $p= 1$

Comment: Thanks @user1952009. This solved my question.